# Setting up a localhost mail server on Mac OSX

Tags: php, email, osx-snow-leopard, localhost

I would love to be able to test php webapps that require emailing registration info etc. on my mac. I downloaded a version of CommuniGate Pro. I need to mail either to an account inside or outside (whichever is best) of the localhost. Again this would be used for testing purposes to verify and debug my code prior to uploading to a hosting service. Any ideas, help and/or examples would be very much appreciated. If it would be easier I could go over to Windows XP. That would just mean setting up wamp and transfering my files over from the mac side via dropbox.

Comment: OS X already has a mailserver built in.

Comment: This is an interesting question but more for http://serverfault.com or http://superuser.com.

Comment: @dystroy **Do not post these kinds of comments**. This encourages users to crosspost (see [here](http://superuser.com/questions/433582/setting-up-a-localhost-mail-server-on-mac-osx)) while a question could easily be migrated. New users don't know about migration and this ends up in a significant overhead for moderators to close/delete questions.

Answer (score 0):

The following tutorial will help you to view emails sent by your local web apps in Mail.app

http://traumwind.de/tindertraum/archives/local_mail_osx.html